# Django Migration issue when we are adding new column to the auth.Group table

Tags: django, django-migrations

We had a CustomUser model in our application and I am trying to add two new columns to the existing auth.Group table as below.

Group.add_to_class('source', models.CharField(max_length=255, default='XXXXXXX'))
Group.add_to_class('tags', TaggableManager(blank=True))

When we try to execute python manage.py makemigrations. Its throwing an error saying inconsistent of migration history.

django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration customuser.0001_initial is applied before its dependency auth.0013_group_source_group_tags on database 'default'.

Need suggestion on the same. How do we handle migrations in such situation. We don't want to create new data base and migrate all the data everytime.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you add **null=True** will work

```
python manage.py makemigrations but_name_here
python manage.py migrate same_name_here
```

Comment: Tried this option. Actually its looking for migration history. We have updated tagging library and tagging library has some update in the migration script. Its pointing to inconsistent migration history

Comment: I faced similar issue before and I made specific name for migrations and works I will edit answer and you can try it